# Kotlin generics and wrong type inference

Tags: generics, kotlin

Consider a general `class Item` and specific `class Event` which inherits it:

```
open class Item<T> {
    fun copyFrom(item: T) {
        if (this is Event && item is Event) {
            owner = item.owner
            value = item.value 
        }
    }
}

class Event : Item<Event> {
    open var owner = ""
    open var value = 0
}
```

Thanks to type inference we don't have to cast Item to Event and we can directly access the `owner` and `value`. However it says the `item` is of type `T` and cannot be cast to `Event` in the `item is Event` clause. I believe this should not happen as this clause is correct in Java?

EDIT:

I am aware of the fact that the `copyFrom` implementation should be done in `Event`, but this is just to demonstrate the type inference issue.

Comment: I don't think there is any compile error except the missing brackets `class Event : Item<Event>()`, which version are you using? And what is the exact error message?

Comment: Can't reproduce after adding missing constructor call at line `class Event : Item<Event> {`

Comment: And it's not part of type inference, it's *smartcast*.

Comment: Please clarify what error you are getting exactly. For now, I'm flagging the question.

Comment: Thanks for the accept :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even when you sort out the syntactical problems: do **not** do this.

You are creating a generic container, which explicitly checks if a distinct **subclass** comes in. To then do a downcast and access fields in the subclass.

This is like the absolute opposite of a good OO design. You base class should know **nothing** about any subclass!